# Processing error while converting xml to dictionary

Tags: python, django

Using form i create xml request and receive xml respond that looks like this:

```
<Root>
   <Header>
      <information>info</information>
   </Header>
   <Main>
      <Product>
         <Name>name1</Name>
         <Description>description1</Description>
         <Price>1</Price>
      </Product>
      <Product>
         <Name>name2</Name>
         <Description>description2</Description>
         <Price>2</Price>
      </Product>
   </Main>
</Root>
```

Then using this function i convert xml data to dictionary:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict

def etree_to_dict(t):
    d = {t.tag: {} if t.attrib else None}
    children = list(t)
    if children:
        dd = defaultdict(list)
        for dc in map(etree_to_dict, children):
            for k, v in dc.iteritems():
                dd[k].append(v)
        d = {t.tag: {k:v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in dd.iteritems()}}
    if t.attrib:
        d[t.tag].update(('@' + k, v) for k, v in t.attrib.iteritems())
    if t.text:
        text = t.text.strip()
        if children or t.attrib:
            if text:
              d[t.tag]['#text'] = text
        else:
            d[t.tag] = text
    return d

e = ET.XML('''
<Root>
   <Header>
      <information>info</information>
   </Header>
   <Main>
      <Product>
         <Name>name1</Name>
         <Description>description1</Description>
         <Price>1</Price>
      </Product>
      <Product>
         <Name>name2</Name>
         <Description>description2</Description>
         <Price>2</Price>
      </Product>
   </Main>
</Root>
''')
```

And store it to database:

```
from pprint import pprint
d = etree_to_dict(e)

pprint(d)
d = etree_to_dict(e)

products = d['Root']['Main']['Product']

for p in products:
    product = Product()
    p.name = p['Name']
    p.description = p['Description']
    p.price = p['Price']

    p.save()
```

And everything worked fine. But now from time to time i stated to receive messages that looks like this:

```
<Root>
   <Header>
      <information>info</information>
   </Header>
   <Main>
      <Error>Product is disable</Error>
   </Main>
</Root>
```

According to this i started to receive this error message: `KeyError at /product/`,  `Exception Value: 'Product'`, and traceback `products = d['Root']['Main']['Product']`.  So i try to change part of my code to this:

```
if products = d['Root']['Main']['Product']:    
  for p in products:
    product = Product()
    p.name = p['Name']
    p.description = p['Description']
    p.price = p['Price']      
    p.save()
else:
  pass
```

But i've got `SyntaxError` in line `if products = d['Root']['Main']['Product']:`. Then I tried to make `products == d['Root']['Main']['Product']` , but now i have another error `local variable 'products' referenced before assignment`. Why does it happen? What i'm doing wrong. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Why don't you use `lxml` and `Xpath` to parse your xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go on and explain the errors you gotten. The syntax error is probably because the "if" is testing a condition, you are not testing a condition but an assignment expression.

The error with the

```
local variable 'products' referenced before assignment
```

is because you are testing if the products equal to

```
d['Root']['Main']['Product']
```

but products is not even declared

To resolve the errors, you can try the modifying codes of yours below:

```
try:
 products = d['Root']['Main']['Product']
except KeyError, e:
 print e, "Product is not there"
if products:
 for p in products:
  product = Product()
  p.name = p['Name']
  p.description = p['Description']
  p.price = p['Price']      
  p.save()

else:
     pass
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer, no i have another error `               products=d['Root']['Main']['Product']`, keyerror `Product`

Comment: @ZagorodniyOlexiy, no problem. This mean that Product is not in the d which is a dictionary, please print d for me and paste the result here ?

Comment: the key error is because you Product key is not there anymore, <Root>
   <Header>
      <information>info</information>
   </Header>
   <Main>
      <Error>Product is disable</Error>
   </Main>
</Root> Product is not there anymore and thats why you get an error!

Comment: I understand, that is why i need exception